# Flex Space Between with fixed width on container just doesnt work for me

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to make a grid system with divs and I can use Text-Align Center but it just doesn't work as well. If I use the flex css the div's just ignore the barrier I created where it's suppose to break up the div's. The problem with not using flex is that I cant use margin to have the edge of the divs aligned with the logo and nav bar's end.

- http://tsuts.tskoli.is/2t/2809984199/skapalon/ - Hosted here

If you check the css you can see two container divs, one whom is commented out and the other one is being used. The one who is being commented out is being using flex and the one I'd like to fix.

- All help is much obliged, Thanks in advance.

  ```
  /*.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100vw - 500px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  }*/
  .projectskort{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 224px;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  }
  ```

Comment: Please post all relevant code in the question itself. Stack Overflow is meant to be a source of reference for everybody. However, if the link you provided dies or the web page changes, this question is no longer useful to future visitors. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using 100vw - 500px instead of a percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove both your .container classes and replace them with

```
.container{
  min-height: 100vh; /*Remove to see the difference*/
  width:72%; /*Modify it for your needs*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*Recommended property*/
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.projectskort{
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 224px;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

That's what i understood from your question

Comment: This does it, I think. Been wrapping my head around that one for a while thanks.

Comment: glad to help, i had the same problem with you when i started coding css with inline blocks + blocks and then i learned [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)  and everything became much easier. Btw please upvote the answer so it can be marked as answered